# When positive score vs negative score results zero it is not showing on profile's summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I noted it today, I don't know if it was already this way, but my last reputation was 5 downvotes and 2 upvotes in one question I asked resulting with no changes in the score.

I think it should show a mini-box with a number zero instead of hiding the mini-box. It just seems weird to me :/

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. Normally we wouldn't show anything, IIRC... Not sure why these two entries still show up separately for you. Gonna need to investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the code to display a `0` properly if that's the case (will show up just like other `0`s do on that page).

With you in the next build (rev: rev 2016.7.13.3757, meta rev: rev 2016.7.13.4740).

Comment: The new picture: _http://i.stack.imgur.com/S2US3.png_